# Use Excel Power Query parameter in Kusto KQL Query

Tags: excel, azure, powerquery, kql, kusto-explorer

I have used the following code in Advanced Editor in power query to pass to KQL the user defined StartDate and EndDate defined in Excel

```
let
   StartDate = DateTime.ToText(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="StartDate"]}[Content]{0}[Column1], "yyyy-MM-dd"),
   EndDate = DateTime.ToText(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="EndDate"]}[Content]{0}[Column1], "yyyy-MM-dd"),
```

and in Kusto query I wrote the following 2 lines to use the previously defined parameters

```
let _startTime = datetime('" & StartDate & '"); let _endTime = datetime('" & EndDate & "');
```

but I'm getting the following errors from Power Query

> Error=Syntax error: Failed to parse datetime literal: 'datetime('" & StartDate & '")'

I tried to change the date formatting as following

```
StartDate = DateTime.ToText(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="StartDate"]}[Content]{0}[Column1], "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"),
EndDate = DateTime.ToText(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="EndDate"]}[Content]{0}[Column1], "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"),
```

but it didn't solve the error

I also found that the sytax I have used `datetime('"StartDate'")`seems to be correct as defined in the following
[help doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/azure-data-explorer) the syntax to pass parameter from power query to kusto query

```
    "StormEvents | where State == """ & State & """ | take 100"
```

Comment: this line is in the powerquery? let _startTime = datetime('" & StartDate & '");

Answer (score 0):

*Need to check below:*

The error can be due to the invalid date format. You can modify it as `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ` that represents a date and time value in `ISO 8601` format.

Here `fffff..` represents a fraction of seconds up to 7 digits.

```
StartDate = DateTime.ToText(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="StartDate"]}[Content]{0}[Column1], "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ")
```

This will properly format the datetime data and allow you to give them to your Kusto query.

*Alternatively,*  you can convert the `startDate and Enddate` variables into the [Text form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-from) as detailed in MS Doc and then pass into the KQL query.

```
let _startTime = datetime(" & Text.From(StartDate) & ");
```

[image]